# Pi estimation using sphere volume

Tags: c++, algorithm, pi, estimation

My task is to calculate the approximate value of pi with an accuracy of at least 10^-6. The Monte Carlo algorithm does not provide the required accuracy. I need to use the calculation only through the volume of the sphere. What do you advise? I would be glad to see examples of code in CUDA or pure C++. Thank you.

Comment: In principle the estimation via Monte Carlo should be able give any accuracy given that you choose the right data type, RNG and let it run for long enough. So is it just not efficient enough for you?

Comment: @PaulG. Dear, I understand what you mean. I mean the Monte Carlo algorithm is very inefficient in this case. In addition, the results for the same number of iterations vary greatly due to the random nature of the x, y, z values.

Comment: Is there a good reason for doing it in 3D instead of 2D with a circle area? Is it just a challenge?

Comment: @PaulG. Just a challenge :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be completely literal about it, you could use a [Darboux integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral) to measure the volume of one octant of the sphere. This code sample measures the area of one quadrant of a circle of radius 2.

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

enum class Relationship { kContained, kDisjoint, kIntersecting };

static const double kRadius = 2;

class Rectangle {
public:
  Rectangle(const double x0, const double y0, const double x1, const double y1)
      : x0_(x0), y0_(y0), x1_(x1), y1_(y1) {}

  double Area() const { return (x1_ - x0_) * (y1_ - y0_); }

  Relationship RelationshipToCircle() const {
    if (x1_ * x1_ + y1_ * y1_ < kRadius * kRadius) {
      return Relationship::kContained;
    }
    if (x0_ * x0_ + y0_ * y0_ > kRadius * kRadius) {
      return Relationship::kDisjoint;
    }
    return Relationship::kIntersecting;
  }

  std::vector<Rectangle> Subdivide() const {
    const double xm = 0.5 * (x0_ + x1_);
    const double ym = 0.5 * (y0_ + y1_);
    return {
        {x0_, y0_, xm, ym},
        {x0_, ym, xm, y1_},
        {xm, y0_, x1_, ym},
        {xm, ym, x1_, y1_},
    };
  }

private:
  double x0_;
  double y0_;
  double x1_;
  double y1_;
};

int main() {
  const Rectangle unit_rectangle{0, 0, kRadius, kRadius};
  double lower_bound = 0;
  double upper_bound = unit_rectangle.Area();
  std::queue<Rectangle> rectangles;
  rectangles.push(unit_rectangle);
  while (upper_bound - lower_bound > 1e-6) {
    const Rectangle r = rectangles.front();
    rectangles.pop();
    switch (r.RelationshipToCircle()) {
    case Relationship::kContained:
      lower_bound += r.Area();
      break;
    case Relationship::kDisjoint:
      upper_bound -= r.Area();
      break;
    case Relationship::kIntersecting:
      for (const Rectangle s : r.Subdivide()) {
        rectangles.push(s);
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << 0.5 * (lower_bound + upper_bound)
            << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Yes, I sketched the code and checked it - it works incredibly fast and accurately. I think this is what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Taylor Series can be used to calculate the value of pi accurate up to 5 decimal places.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
double pi(int n) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    int sign = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {           
        sum += sign/(2.0*i+1.0);
        sign *= -1;
    }
    return 4.0*sum;
}
int main(){
   cout << pi(10000000) << endl;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any "volume of the sphere" in this answer.

Comment: @trincot Right, I'm interested in a solution using the volume of a sphere. Otherwise, I could have used the excellent Chudnovsky algorithm.